# C no printf to second line after scanf

Tags: c

How to print in same line after scanf?

my code:

```
int ui;

char up_from_down=179;

printf("%c",up_from_down);scanf("%d",&ui);printf("1                                              %c\n",up_from_down);
```

I don't know or explain well how I want it to be

so i add ss

ss now:[image]

I want it to be:[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your terminal supports ANSI Escape Codes, this will move the cursor up one line and then to column 10 and resume printing on the same line as the input for `ui`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ui;
    char up_from_down=179;

    printf("%c",up_from_down);
    scanf("%d",&ui);
    printf ( "\033[1A");//move cursor up one line
    printf ( "\033[10C");//move cursor 10 places
    printf("1                                              %c\n",up_from_down);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want the printing to more closely follow the input, use `%n` to capture the number of characters processed by `scanf` and use that value in the ANSI Escape Code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ui = 0;
    int col = 0;
    char up_from_down=179;

    printf ( "%c", up_from_down);
    fflush ( stdout);//no newline in printf so force printing
    if ( 1 == scanf ( "%d%n", &ui, &col)) {
        col += 2;
        printf ( "\033[1A");//move cursor up one line
        printf ( "\033[%dC", col);//move cursor to col
        printf("1                                              %c\n",up_from_down);
    }
    return 0;
}
```